# 'node_modules/ngx-webstorage/ngx-webstorage' has no exported member 'Ng2Webstorage'

Tags: angular, jhipster

There is the below error in angular project:

```
ERROR in I:/Apps/App/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/jit-polyfills.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es7/reflect' in 'I:\Apps\research\App\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models'
ERROR in src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts(6,10): error TS2305: Module '"I:/Apps/research/App/node_modules/ngx-webstorage/ngx-webstorage"' has no exported member 'Ng2Webstorage'.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

In recent version of ngx-webstorage module name changed to 'NgxWebstorageModule'

Answer (score 0):

Try `npm install` after deleting current node_modules folder and package-lock.json

Comment: Checked with npm install after deleting both but below error occur: 
ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es6/reflect' in 'E:\EmployeeApp\dms\src'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/jit-polyfills.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es7/reflect' in 'E:\EmployeeApp\dms\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models'
i ?wdm?: Failed to compile.

Comment: Can you add your package.json contents in questions? @Nimesh

Comment: "dependencies": {"@angular/animations": "^7.2.14", "@angular/common": "^7.2.14","@angular/compiler": "^7.2.14", "@angular/core": "^7.2.14","@angular/forms": "^7.2.14", "@angular/http": "^7.2.14","@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.14","@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.14", "@angular/router": "^7.2.14", "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2", "bootstrap": "^4.3.1", "core-js": "^3.0.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^1.9.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  }

Comment: "devDependencies":{ "@angular-devkit/build-angular":"~0.13.0","@angular/cli": "^7.3.8","@angular/compiler-cli":"^7.2.14","@angular/language-service": "^7.2.14","@types/jasmine": "~3.3.12","@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2","@types/node": "~11.13.8","codelyzer": "~5.0.1","jasmine-core": "~3.4.0","jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1", "karma": "~4.1.0", "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0","karma-cli": "~2.0.0","karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter":"^2.0.5","karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1", "karma-jasmine-html-reporter":"^1.4.2", "protractor": "~5.4.2", "ts-node": "~8.1.0","tslint": "~5.16.0","typescript": "^3.2.4"}